# Nginx match any word in if statement except one

Tags: nginx, regex

I'm using the following if statement regex in `nginx` config to match and block some bad requests inside request uri. These bad queries request always only one argument but every time with random name (and alphanum count). They also always hit the homepage.

Example of bad query:
`/?some1bad0query2=nminkvywbjfdysnvhp`

```
if ($request_uri ~ "[\w]{5,25}\=[\w]{5,25}$") {
  return 403;
}
```

How can I modify this regex to exclude matching some argument names like `key` or `query` (ie. /?query=somestring) ?

I tried to use round brackets and `?(!query)` but no luck.

Please help me correct this regex statement. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that just a poor example, because `query=somestring` doesn't match your regular expression anyway, as `query` is less than 6 characters long?

Comment: yes definitely it was wrong. corrected regex to start with 5 length arg name (query). but I still need an example of how I can mitigate this attack and bypass such good arguments whitelist (like query, search etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. Use a [negative lookahead assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) or use a [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map).

For example:

```
if ($request_uri ~ "(?!query)\w{5,25}=\w{5,25}$") { return 403; }
```

---

The advantage of the `map` is that regular expressions are evaluated in order until a match is found, so complex lookahead expressions can be avoided.

For example:

```
map $request_uri $reject {
    ~*^/\?query=                0;
    "~*^/\?\w{5,25}=\w{5,25}$"  1;
}
server {
    ...
    if ($reject) { return 403; }
    ...
}
```

The `map` block lives outside of the `server` block. If the rule only applies to URIs which begin with `/?`, you should add that to the regular expression (as shown in my second example).

Comment: Thanks, Richard! The map seems to be more elegant solution for me. Tested and it works flawlesly. Btw. my mistake in the if statement was that I put the ?! block after argument